# How to change Primefaces rating tag's icon?

Tags: primefaces

I use a p:rating tag like this.

```
<p:rating id="ratingID" value="#{manageBean.clientDetails.level}" styleClass="rating"/>
```

I want to change the image instead of star. I surfed google and got the below code.

```
.rating .ui-rating-star a, .ui-rating-cancel a {  
  background-image:url(../Images/fire.jpg);   
   display: block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 16px;       
}
```

But it is not working for me.

Is their any other way for this?

Comment: can you try adding !important in your background-image?

Comment: do you need to change only the "on" star rating (the yellow one in the example) or even the "off" (the gray one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the "on" (the yellow star) image using this:

```
.rating .ui-rating-star-on a{
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:new-document.png']}")  !important;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 16px;  
    background-position: center;
}
```

If you want to change also the other images would be more tricky. Apparently checking the example in the Primefaces showcase [website](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/rating.xhtml) I can see this is what they are using:

[image: Primefaces Star Rating]

I think if you would just create the same image picture as that and following the size (16X80) as well then replace the pictures accordingly, you can achieve achieve your desired effect.

Haven't tried it though on my end.

Comment: So in the end it is all just html, css and javascript... ;-)

Comment: and pictures if you're at it. ;) haha. so does this answer your question? if it does please mark it as accepted. thanks.